# Clipper chip (SKIPJACK) key exchange protocol

Tags: key-exchange, skipjack

According to [the Wikipedia page for NSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Agency#Clipper_chip) (emphasis mine):

> However, NSA's Fortezza hardware-based encryption cards, created for
>   the Clipper project, are still used within government, and NSA
>   ultimately published the design of the SKIPJACK cipher (**but not the
>   key exchange protocol**) used on the cards.

However, the [NIST publication describing SKIPJACK](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/skipjack/skipjack.pdf) also describes a Key Exchange Algorithm (KEA).

My question is simple: Is the Wikipedia page wrong, or is it talking about something else?

Comment: FWIW, the Wikipedia page no longer includes that remark. It was apparently added in [this edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=National_Security_Agency&diff=146628018) back in 2007, and removed in [this recent edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=National_Security_Agency&diff=prev&oldid=562061258), which also added a citation to the NIST publication you link to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia is wrong in this case - just like the NIST publication describing SKIPJACK already implies by being titled [*"SKIPJACK **and KEA Algorithm Specifications**"*](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/skipjack/skipjack.pdf). In fact, on page 17 of that paper, you will find infos about *KEA exchange for Email* and on page 12, there's *a summary of a full KEA exchange between devices A and B…*

**A summary of a full KEA exchange between devices A and B** (page 12)

[image: A summary of a full KEA exchange between devices A and B]

**A summary of an Email KEA exchange between devices A and B** (page 17)

[image: A summary of an Email KEA exchange between devices A and B]

**On a side-note:** If you check the Wikipedia entry, it shows that Wikipedia entry has been edited meanwhile, just like [@ilmari-karonen already mentioned in a comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8761/clipper-chip-skipjack-key-exchange-protocol#comment18080_8761).

Comment: So this is more or less two Diffie-Hellman key exchanges (both half-ephemeral for the full KEA, one half-ephemeral and one static for the email variant) in parallel, with an application of a "strange hash" (build from Skipjack encryption) on the result.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Correct. The Clipper Chip itself used the Skipjack encryption algorithm for transmission of information, and the Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm for distribution of the cryptographic session keys between peers.